# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'encrypt' of undefined

Tags: javascript, rsa, sha256

I want to encrypt using **RSA_OAEP_SHA256** on the JavaScript side.
I am using the third party library **asmcrypto.js** :

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/asmCrypto/0.22.0/asmcrypto.js"></script>
    <script>
        var encrypted = asmCrypto.RSA_OAEP_SHA256.encrypt(stringToBeEncrypted, pubkey, "");
    </script>
```

getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'encrypt' of undefined.

Does anybody know the solution or any example that would help?

Comment: `asmCrypto.RSA_OAEP_SHA256 === undefined`

Comment: Use the ".all" version -> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/asmCrypto/0.22.0/asmcrypto.all.js

Comment: Thanks. That error got disappeared now!! But now it is printing below error in browser console. rsa.js:41 Uncaught TypeError: unexpected key type at RSA_OAEP.RSA_reset (rsa.js:41) at RSA_OAEP.reset (pkcs1.js:40) at new RSA_OAEP (pkcs1.js:19) at Object.rsa_oaep_sha256_encrypt_bytes [as encrypt] (exports-oaep-sha256.js:11) at get (MntRole.jsp:229) at <anonymous>:1:1  Does I have to import all those .js files mentioned in error stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I found the solution, I am sharing it here so that it will be helpful to someone.

1. I changed the library and used **jsencrypt.min.js** [JSEncrypt](https://github.com/alfaro28/jsencrypt/blob/master/bin/jsencrypt.min.js)
   It is an updated one that supports OAEP padding.
2. JavaScript Code :

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/RSO/includes/jsencrypt.min.js"></script>
function get(tmpSubmit)
{
  <%
  String key = BouncyCastlePemUtils.readPublicKey();
  System.out.println("readPublicKey: " + key);
  %>    

  alert('<%=key %>');
  var publicKey = '<%=key %>';
  var password = "Dhiraj is the author";
  var RSAEncrypt = new JSEncrypt();
  RSAEncrypt.setPublicKey(publicKey);
  var encryptedPass = RSAEncrypt.encrypt(password, true);
  document.write("encryptedPass: "+encryptedPass)

}
```

3. Generate Public and Private Key using openssl, please check the link below for commands.

[openssl commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKDT2.png)

4. Java Class to encrypt and decrypt data:

```js
package com.demo.rsa;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.Security;
    import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
    import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
    import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
    
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
    
    import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
    
    import com.demo.util.CommonProperties;
    
    public class PEMDemo implements Serializable {
    
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
        public String encrypt(String plainText, RSAPublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
            Cipher cipher = getCipher();
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            
            return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encryptedText);
        }
    
        public String decrypt(String cipherText, RSAPrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
            byte[] cipherBytes;
            cipherBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(cipherText);
            Cipher cipher = getCipher();
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            byte[]  decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);
            
            return new String(decryptedText, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
    
        private Cipher getCipher() throws Exception {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            return Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding", new BouncyCastleProvider());
        }
    
        public static RSAPublicKey getPublicKey(){
            RSAPublicKey publicKey = null;
            try {
                File publicKeyFile = new File(CommonProperties.propBag.getProperty("RSA_CONFIG_PATH")+"public_key.pem");
                publicKey = BouncyCastlePemUtils.readX509PublicKey(publicKeyFile);
            } catch (InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return publicKey;
        }
        
        public static RSAPrivateKey getPrivateKey(){
            RSAPrivateKey privateKey = null;
            try {
                File privateKeyFile = new File(CommonProperties.propBag.getProperty("RSA_CONFIG_PATH")+"private_key.pem");
                privateKey = BouncyCastlePemUtils.readPKCS8PrivateKey(privateKeyFile);
            } catch (InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return privateKey;
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args){
            PEMDemo rsaEncriptDecrypt = new PEMDemo();
            String encrypted;
            try {
                encrypted = rsaEncriptDecrypt.encrypt("This is plain text.", getPublicKey());
                System.out.println("encrypted: " + encrypted);
                
                // JS Encrypted cipher text
                encrypted = "voxgNKCtKy6wGL/g9oi/jUqwm4lnT+Ais4ZaJ5OwJ4gozjTHl3L7yabB04tyV9UmuxfGb6EywZvrpuZRIKtqWPzO+UgW0A+5g9nPjXtDPI0qMzuv7i1E7WVjM4isJBwOC4yPdttXi4h/vbzOaR5J5r8mbyHdnxkqtuDn3o5jXOM=";
                
                String decrypted = rsaEncriptDecrypt.decrypt(encrypted, getPrivateKey());
                System.out.println("decrypted: " + decrypted);
                
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
            
        }
    }
```

5. Utility class to read Public and Private Key from .PEM file

```js
package com.demo.rsa;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.security.KeyFactory;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
    import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
    import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
    import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
    import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
    
    import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject;
    import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader;
    
    import com.demo.util.CommonProperties;
    
    public class BouncyCastlePemUtils {
    
        public static RSAPublicKey readX509PublicKey(File file) throws InvalidKeySpecException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    
            try (FileReader keyReader = new FileReader(file);
                 PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(keyReader)) {
    
                PemObject pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject();
                byte[] content = pemObject.getContent();
                X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(content);
                return (RSAPublicKey) factory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
            }
        }
    
        public static RSAPrivateKey readPKCS8PrivateKey(File file) throws InvalidKeySpecException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    
            try (FileReader keyReader = new FileReader(file);
                 PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(keyReader)) {
    
                PemObject pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject();
                byte[] content = pemObject.getContent();
                PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(content);
                return (RSAPrivateKey) factory.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);
            }
        }
        
        public static String readPublicKey() throws IOException {
            File publicKeyFile = new File(CommonProperties.propBag.getProperty("RSA_CONFIG_PATH")+"public_key.pem");
            StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(publicKeyFile))){
                 String s = st.toString();
                  while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                      st.append(s);
            }
            return st.toString();
        }
    }
```

6. Maven Dependancy:

```html
6. Maven Dependancy:
<dependency>
             <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
             <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
             <version>${bouncycastle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```